# Getting error while introducing star symbol

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I am interested in creating a star symbol in Mathematica. But I am getting some error saying `Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First`. How to over come this error. I am using  Mathematica 12.2 version in ubuntu 18.

```
star = First[
  First[ImportString[
    ExportString[Style["✶", FontSize -> 16], "PDF"], 
    "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]
emptyhex = 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.1], Black}], White, star}, 
  ImageSize -> 30]
filledhex = Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Black, star}, ImageSize -> 30]
```

Comment: Looks like a version 12.+ change in `ImportString`. It works fine version 11.3 (windows 10-64b). I get the same error message in v12.2 (wolfram cloud). The if you check `Head[First[ImportString[....]]]` it is `Image` (it used to be `Graphics`). So check if the fix `star = First[Show@First[ImportString[...]]]` works in your version/OS.

Comment: @kglr is it a bug then?

Comment: I doubt it is a bug. More likely one of those cases where documentation lags behind updates.

Comment: Your right @kglr, In my previous code which was written in version 11 have no problem.  Now I have uninstalled and installed the new version 12.2. What to do now. Your previous suggestion is not working.

Comment: why not use `{Thickness[0.142857],{FilledCurve[{{{0,2,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0}}},{{{6.29974,4.15195},{4.39902,4.15195},{3.45406,2.51402},{2.5091,4.15195},{0.613775,4.15195},{1.55334,5.79889},{0.613775,7.44762},{2.5091,7.44762},{3.45406,9.07835},{4.39902,7.44762},{6.29974,7.44762},{5.35478,5.79889},{6.29974,4.15195}}}]}}` (which is what you get in version 11)